# could not be able to work with ListActivity in android

Tags: android, listactivity

I want to make a `ListItem` selected as app starts and get the text/value of selected item,but I'm unable to do.

**Code**

```
public class MenuList extends ListActivity {

String[] classNames = {"MainActivity", "example"}; 
//private View currentSelectedView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MenuList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classNames));

}   
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);      
    String itemText= classNames[position];

    Toast.makeText(MenuList.this, itemText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
}       
  }
```

through this I get the text/value of listItem but Im unable to make a listItem pre-selected.
can any-one tell me how to do so..?

Comment: do you want to make listview with radiobutton/checkbox and choice remains pre-selected??

Comment: this is list with only text!

Comment: use SharedPreferences to save list view position..

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to android and I don't know how to use SharedPreferences, but if you don't mind can you give me some code snap! this will be your kind!

Comment: do you want to show that list item is selected by changing background?

Comment: yes and I want to get the text of that selected item as well...!

Answer (score 0):

To set the selector to your `ListView` add `android:background="@drawable/list_bg"` to your Activity_main.xml like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and create `list_bg.xml` in your drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: I have done this and added one line of code in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentsView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MenuList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classNames));

}   ` this gives me `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'` exception. what to do now..??

Comment: if you are using ListActivity then id attribute of your layout should be android:id="@android:id/list"